# @font-face appears jagged at high resolutions

Tags: css, font-face

I am using@font-face on high resolutions the font appears distorted please find screen below.
http://goo.gl/Cwskw

While on low resolutions it looks fine.
http://goo.gl/w47uU

Is there any solution so I can make the font look same in all resolutions.

Comment: That's... not what high or low resolution means. Also, it looks equally bad in both images.

Comment: @boltclock thanks for your reply. If you see it appears clear in http://quick-markup.com/p/519706aa484f9

Comment: @boltclock please ignore my last comments. thanks for your reply. If you see it appears clear in http://quick-markup.com/p/519706aa484f9 I am not sure of words high and low resolution. The above image is a ordinary laptop and other is full hd screen.